# How to use laravel as proxy files between systems?

Tags: laravel, guzzle, php-curl

I need you help to find a way to be a 'proxy' between the frontend and a third-party software component using Laravel.

The third-party software it is in my company's network and it generate the files on-demand.
For sample, If i hit against http://mycompany-third-party.com/12/csv, It will read the data from their database and delivery it to download as response (in this case a csv file).

But I can't allow the users reach out the third-party endpoint directly, so I want to use laravel(guzzle) to ask the file to the third-party and then redirectly to the specific client without store it in my local disk.

How can i do something like this using laravel/guzzle or other library?

Here is my best guess:

```php
 $response = Http::withOptions(['stream' => true])->withHeaders([
            'X-Metabase-Session' => $this->token,
       ])->post('http://mycompany-third-party.com/12/csv');

        $headers = $response->headers();

        return response($response->getBody())->withHeaders($headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey Guys I study more and I have found a solution. To to this we need to use the [Streamed Downloads](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses).

Here is my answer:

```php
        $response = Http::withOptions(['stream' => true])->withHeaders([
            'X-Metabase-Session' => $this->token,
        ])->post(your-3th-url);


        return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($response) {
            echo $response->getBody()->getContents();
        }, 'fileName.extType');
```

see you.